# Could not handle http error on azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, web-config, http-error

The solve of my problem: 
Added:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
 <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
  <error statusCode="404" path="/404.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
  <error statusCode="403" path="/403.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
  <error statusCode="500" path="/500.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
</httpErrors>
```

Removed:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/403.html" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.html" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/500.html" />
    </customErrors>
```

---

I applied httpErrors in Web.config on my project then when I test on localhost it's ok. However, when I publish to azure it couldn't handle http error 500 and 403. For example:

I tried url: www.mywebsite.com/content
Response on localhost: Ok i am getting 500 page or 403
Response on azure: "The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

My web.config:

```
<httpErrors  errorMode="Custom">
              <error statusCode="403" subStatusCode="14" path="403.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
              <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="19" path="500.html" responseMode="Redirect"/>
</httpErrors>
```

Why it happens, I don't understand. Do you know anything about this problem?

Comment: Do you have something like `<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="DefaultError.htm"/>` in you Web.config?

Comment: Yes i am using like this: <customErrors mode="On" xdt:Transform="Replace">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/404.html" />
    </customErrors>

Comment: And what happens when you set `mode="Off"`? Also, with `mode="On"`, do you have something like `<error statusCode="403" redirect="~/403.html" />`?

Comment: @AlLelopath thank you it worked but i needed add a few things like this:<remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />

Comment: Tell me which part worked and I will post that as an answer so you can check it off

Comment: @AlLelopath i already added the solution to in my first post

Comment: You should at least answer your own question with an official answer rather than putting the answer in the question.